# Having issues with watchman

Tags: watchman

Can someone tell me how to remove watchman from linux terminal? Going to try a different nodewatcher. I tried  "sudo apt-get --purge remove watchman" and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have build it from source.

Usually you can just use:

```
make uninstall
```

or

```
sudo make uninstall
```

if the app was installed as root.
from build directory.